# Access changes table Relationships by itself

Tags: ms-access, relationship, lookup-tables

I am struggling with an issue in designing my Access database.

I am a caregiver, and part of my job is taking clients out into the community. I am attempting to build a catalog of outings to help the employees at our company come up with and store ideas for these. I want to store information for each of up to 5 types of events that clients can do at a location. That information includes the event type, when it runs and doesn't, and how much it'll cost, all of which would be user-selectable. (Separately in the same table, I want to include contact information and information that helps the user search for event locations, such as the ZIP code.) I have attempted to normalize the database by spreading event information across fields in the main table, linked to lookup tables. I am aware that Access [has a limit of 32 relationships per table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=General&text=2%20gigabytes%2C%20minus%20the%20space,be%20as%20large%20as%202GB.).

To help staff find event types, I am trying to set up a method for categorizing them. That requires setting up nested lookup tables, as shown in the first picture. [image]
 If I understand correctly, the additional "copies" of those lookup tables are aliases. When I save the setup for the relationships between those aliased lookup tables, close the Relationships window, and open it again, I find Access has changed them, as shown in the second picture. [image] This happens whether I delete the lookup table information for each field in Datasheet View. I don't understand why it does this or how to fix it.

Comment: The issue will go away if you fix your table structure. Personal data and Events should be *separate* tables, with one-to-many relation.

Comment: It changes them because there really is only one OutingType table. Your structure is not normalized enough.

Comment: In other words, I should have tables for the 5 event type slots each linked to the fields for personal information, such as wheelchair-bound, family-friendly, pet-friendly, and serves/allows alcohol. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

In the object browser I see that you have only one table: `t_OutingType`. Therefore, the "tables" `t_OutingType_2`, `t_OutingType_3` are just aliases; "pointers" to the same table (like a shortcut to a document). When you save the relationships and close the window, the relationship information is written to the *metadata* of the database. When you re-open the Relationships window Access re-builds the relationship diagram from the metadata, and it does not include the redundant aliases.

Additional advice:

Whenever you find yourself duplicating columns in a table, e.g., `Event_1`, `Event_2`, ... a little voice in your head should start shouting "Are you sure that's a good idea?" Imagine if you want to search the database for events that fall on a certain date. With the table layout described above you would need to ...

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE EventDate_1 = [theDate] OR EventDate_2 = [theDate] OR EventDate_3 = [theDate] ...
```

It's almost always better to split the Event information into a separate child table and maintain an *association table* between the child table and its parent.

Comment: I am building this database as a courtesy for my company and to gain database experience. When combined with [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description#normalizing-an-example-table), your point about realizing that my current design is bad, is a point on the road of the latter. Today I learned something very important and useful. Thank you.